# how many times this loop will be executed?

Tags: c

I write this code, which takes an integer number (t) as input from the user. A loop will be executed just 't' times. But I find that it runs for `(t-1)` times. For example, if I give input `3`, it runs only `2` times. Can anyone please explain why this is happening?

I tried and used `scanf("%s", &str)`, it works, but then I can't take a string as input that contains spaces.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int t;
    scanf("%d", &t);
    while(t--)
      {
        char str[100];
        gets(str);
        printf("%s\n", str);
      }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Never use the `gets` function; it's inherently unsafe, and has been removed from the latest version of the language. `fgets` can be used safely, but is a little more complicated.

Comment: The loop body runs `t` times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scanf("%d", &t)` consumes only the numeral in the input stream and leaves the remaining characters. When you enter a numeral and press enter, there is a newline character after the numeral.

The first `gets` reads this newline and returns a string that is empty except for the newline. The first iteration of the loop prints this blank line.

Answer (score 1):

Loop is iterating 3 times as it should.But it seems that it is iterating 2 times only because of the reason that the `\n` character left behind by `gets` in the buffer is read in second iteration.
For first iteration, when you enter a string and the press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the `\n` character go to the buffer with the string. `gets` stop reading when it encounters `\0`, leaving `\n` in the buffer. On next iteration this `\n` (non printable character) is read by `gets` and then printed to terminal.

---

NOTE: Never use `gets` function. It is no longer is the part of standard C. Use [`fgets`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html#tag_16_142) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can also use the `scanf` function to resolve your problem that the string is not accepting anything after a `SPACE` . Also, the loop is running `(t-1)` times because the buffer is not being cleared due to the use of `gets()` . In order to resolve this, you can use the `getch()` function to clear the buffer. The following code should work I guess,

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int t;
    scanf("%d", &t);
    while(t--)
     {
       char str[100];
       scanf("%[^\n]c",&str);
       printf("%s\n", str);
       getch();
     }
return 0;
```

}

In this code, the `getch()` will clear the buffer by accepting the useless value. Also as far as `scanf()` is considered, the `^` inside the `scanf` tells the function that it needs to take the input till the character after the `^` is encountered which in this case is an escape sequence of `NEW LINE` . I have tried using some small words as well instead of the newline and it has worked as well. Hope this clears your issue :)